# What symbol is this?

Tags: identification, components, schematics, electrical, symbol

Does anyone know what this step between the two lines mean? [image: Squigle]

Comment: Looks like a 'break' signal to indicate a longer length cable.

Answer (score 6):

This could indicate a twisted pair. I have personally used a similar symbol for that and also some websites agree with this, such as [this one](https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/lines-wires-conductors-symbols.htm)

[image]

It also looks like SolidWorks Electrical has this symbol for this purpose too:
[image]
(the image is taken from [this forum](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/208254))

It doesn't seem to be standardized, so we see many variations.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to be standardized, so we see many variations." That's the great thing about standards.  There are so many to choose from. -MAXIM Integrated.